# How does Thumb Mode work in a more energy-efficient way than ARM?

Tags: arm, cpu-architecture, thumb

As the `Thumb` use 16-bit instructions while `ARM` use 32-bit ones. By what means does the processor make it more energy efficient? By turning off some unit?

Comment: The energy efficiency will depend on the chip.  Ie, the chemical processes to make the transistors, etc.  As you can look up two 16bit instructions, the memory bus is 1/2 as busy.  The BUS transistors consume a lot of energy as they distance between chips is greater and there may be multiple memory devices on the bus.  This is not programming related and is better on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Who says Thumb has anything to do with energy efficiency? (genuine question; I'm interested in where this came from) Certainly the original design was purely for code density, i.e. so that designs need less ROM, and can also use cheaper 16-bit ROMs but still manage an instruction fetch every cycle. It probably made the early CPUs consume _more_ power, since just they just had an extra Thumb-to-ARM decoder stage bolted to the front of the pipeline.

Comment: @Notlikethat I think it comes from marketing material arm licensees produce / use. Especially MCU world against 8/16 bit architectures. High code density allows less reading from flash, etc...

Comment: I think it is pretty obvious that arm based ebooks ran for days where others run for hours on the same charge.  It is not a thumb vs arm thing or even arm vs other processor thing, there are a number of factors that can be done, not unlike compiling your code for the debugger adds a bunch of junk, but if you actually tried to make it lean and mean and efficient instead you could run faster or have a smaller binary, etc.

Comment: Not sure what your context is here, but for example the new cortex-m based microcontrollers that have replaced the arm7tdmi based microcontrollers consume far less power, I dont think it has anything to do with arm instruction set vs thumb instruction set.  A lot may have to do with the years of experience in processor design and chip technology, etc that have happened.  thumb without thumb2 is certainly simpler, but back in the day the compilers generated about 10 percent more code for the thumb version than the arm.

Comment: quite clear that an arm or thumb instruction set can do more per clock cycle than a traditional pic.  But why cant a pic32 even which is really a mips, which is a much simpler instruction set than arm from a decoding and implementation perspective, compete on power?    there are a number of tricks you can play and I imagine some of that is in the design, some in the chip technology.   Imagine how little power a pdp8 would take today if we were to build one, as far as the core is concerned, you need a ton of ram though to do anything competitive. lc-3 is another example...

Comment: @dwelch I'm pretty sure I saw such text in marketing material around early 2000 when people were having laugh about having 32-bit MCUs for embedded systems. It was somewhere between overkill to inefficiency on all possible buzz word. I always thought TDMI was just an answer to those...

Comment: I am obviously an arm fan but, I honestly also never thought anyone would compete on low power, still dont believe it when even ti says their cortex-m4 of all things is their low power thing.  I do see first hand what marketing produces vs what engineering and software produce.  We know ARM has great lawyers protecting their IP, perhaps they have great marketing and sales too...To really win the IoT thing though you need programmability as well as low power as well as an internet connection all in one package, will see who ends up winning or dominating that.

Comment: It baffles me that mips had and still has as much of a chance as arm in these markets, why isnt mips there, why isnt every 10th phone mips based, equivalent performance both processing and mips per watt?

Comment: @dwelch May be somewhere between marketing and vendor push due to IP style business. Also ARM always had better SW support. MIPS were never there for me, literally. I never saw it. Then of course mobile biz came and crucial market dominance happened for ARM.

Comment: @auselen, Exactly, the potential was there, the design probably could have worked but from a whole company/system perspective the departments/teams did not all come together, and there could be other factors too (attitudes and opinions), but nevertheless we are where we are, for every other processor in a device you have you probably have a few arms.  for every x86 computer the average person has several arm based devices (not to mention the few in the x86 box).  Just interesting stuff watching how these things unfold.

Answer (score 1):

Everything remaining same, THUMB instructions will cause less amount of reads from RAM (FLASH if XIP), less pressure on the I-Caches for the same amount of compute done using ARM instructions. Since memory consumption is reduced so would your page faults and resulting page-ins from non-volatile storage. That said, if the savings were significant or quantifiable the ARM marketing team would have put out comparison numbers.